# How to fix AAPT: error: resource drawable/tt (aka com.example.polyresults:drawable/tt) not found

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm getting this error many times when I run my project.

```
ERROR:C:\Users\Elius H Himel\AndroidStudioProjects\PolyResults\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_loging.xml:2: AAPT: error: resource drawable/tt (aka com.example.polyresults:drawable/tt) not found.
```

How do I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your drawable tt(image or layout) is deleted or not present. Add it, the error will go.